# How to check if date is between two dates regardless of year

Tags: swift, date

How can I check if any date is between two dates?
For instance I want to check if current date is between 15 December and 15 January.

This can be any year so my current date could be 15 December 2023 and it should return true. If it's 14 of December or 16 January any year it should return false. 31 December should return true.

This is what I tried:

```
let now = currentDateProvider()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: now)
guard let start = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(year)-01-01"),
      let end = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(year)-01-07") else {
   return false
}
if start <= now && now <= end {
    return true
}

guard let start = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(year)-12-01"),
      let end = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(year)-12-31") else {
    return false
}
let value = start <= now && now <= end
return value
```

But it seams a bit buggy because if my time zone is UTC +2 then the end date gives me 30 December 22:00:00 because UTC + 2 is 31 December 00:00 - 2 hours it gives you 30 December instead of 31.

Ideally I would like to not have to separate checks for dates and just have one inclusive check between 15-december and 15 January rather than check 15-december - 31 December and 1 janury to 7 - January.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the date components for month and day for the date and do a simple comparison of the values

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: date)
let inPeriod = (components.month! == 12 && components.day! >= 15) || (components.month! == 1 && components.day! <= 15)
```

Simple test case

```
var testDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2021, month: 12, day: 14))!

for _ in 1...34 {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: testDate)
    print(testDate, (components.month! == 12 && components.day! >= 15) || (components.month! == 1 && components.day! <= 15))
    testDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: testDate)!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore the year especially if the turn of the year is within the interval. And as the **current** date is involved practically you want to check if the date is within December of the **current** year and Januar of the **next** year

My suggestion is to get the year component from the current date, then build the start date by setting month to 12 and day to 15 and the end date by adding one day and one month to the start date which points to Jan 16 in the next year.

```
let currentDate = Date.now
let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: currentDate)
let startComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: 12, day: 15)
let startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: startComponents)!
let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: 1), to: startDate)!

if currentDate >= startDate && currentDate < endDate {
    print("isValid")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to redeem myself!

1. Didn't saw that you are looking for a solution that takes into account your TimeZone
2. Didn't saw that you wanted something that are only interested into intervals but not in the years.

I have to confess, sometimes I read without attention to the questions, specially the ones that I think it's easy.

Hope the solution bellow meet your needs. As other college said, there is no way you can't take into account the year, but you can Mock the year inside the function, just like you did.

Look for yourself and see if you like my solution better or stick with yours:

```swift
import Foundation

let f = ISO8601DateFormatter()
f.formatOptions = .withFullDate
f.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PST")

func thisDate(_ date: Date, isBetweenthisMonth initialMonth: Int, andDay initialDay: Int, andThisOtherMonth finalMonth: Int, andThisOtherDay finalDay: Int) -> Bool {
    var isBetween = false
    
    let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date)
    
    let initialYear = year
    var finalYear = year
    
    if finalMonth < initialMonth {
        finalYear += finalYear
    }
    
    let initialFakeData = f.date(from: "\(initialYear)-\(initialMonth)-\(initialDay)")!
    let finalFakeData = f.date(from: "\(finalYear)-\(finalMonth)-\(finalDay)")!
    
    if (date > initialFakeData && date < finalFakeData) {
        isBetween = true
    }
    
    return isBetween
}


// Some test cases to pass
let date = f.date(from: "2022-11-01")!

print(thisDate(date, isBetweenthisMonth: 12, andDay: 02, andThisOtherMonth: 02, andThisOtherDay: 23) == false ? "False" : "Something wrong.")
print(thisDate(date, isBetweenthisMonth: 10, andDay: 02, andThisOtherMonth: 01, andThisOtherDay: 15) == true ? "True" : "Something wrong.")

let date2 = f.date(from: "2022-12-31")!

print(thisDate(date2, isBetweenthisMonth: 12, andDay: 30, andThisOtherMonth: 01, andThisOtherDay: 01) == true ? "True" : "Something wrong.")
print(thisDate(date2, isBetweenthisMonth: 01, andDay: 01, andThisOtherMonth: 01, andThisOtherDay: 15) == false ? "False" : "Something wrong.")

let date_now = f.date(from: f.string(from: Date()))!

print(thisDate(date_now, isBetweenthisMonth: 11, andDay: 08, andThisOtherMonth: 11, andThisOtherDay: 10) == true ? "True" : "Something wrong.")
print(thisDate(date_now, isBetweenthisMonth: 12, andDay: 01, andThisOtherMonth: 02, andThisOtherDay: 01) == false ? "False" : "Something wrong.")
```

I don't know how to use XCTest into playground, so I mock some tests in the final code.

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirement to ignore the year.

Comment: Didn't saw that. That you want ignoring the year.

Comment: You can make a better signature... my creativity is not good for functions signatures.

Comment: Have to confess, I like @Joakim Danielson better!

Comment: If you only interested into the problem TimeZone ```import Foundation

let now = Date.now
let tz = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PST")
let diff = tz?.secondsFromGMT()
let tz_now = now.addingTimeInterval(Double(diff!))```